# SSIS Job Importing Quotation Marks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a SSIS job that runs under a schedule on SQL Server 2008 R2.  Ths job takes multiple comma-separated text files and imports them into SQL tables.  I created this SSIS package about 4 years ago and I have periodically updated it without issues.  I recently had to make a minor change to one data flow task.  This worked fine on my machine, but when I put the job on the server, it errored out.  On closer inspection, the reason it errored out was that the values it was trying to put into SQL tables all included quotation marks around the values.  This would cause errors on the non-string values (like integer types) or just bring the quotes in on the string fields.

My source text files do contain quotation marks around some of the values.  Here are two example lines:

"536518*1","A120","B002209A12","AA",01-16-14,3,0.000,1555.50,"0",0,"UA",12-17-13,"","KS","A","04","1","MNS","AM"

"540039*1","G040","YPCILANHA/S224","Y",01-16-14,2,0.080,905.28,"0",0,"SM",01-16-14,"","","A","02","1","MNA","AM"

Therefore, on my Flat File Connection Manager, I have the "Text qualifier" set to quotation marks, like this:

[image: TextQualifier]

What is really strange is that the data flow task that is having issues is not the one I modified.  I did not change the SQL table definitions in any way.  In the end, I added derivied columns in my DFT to strip out the quotation marks manually.  Example:

```
REPLACE([Column 0],"\"","")
```

Since this has to be done for each row, I had to to this 18 times, which was pretty annoying.

Another really strange symptom is that this works fine from my laptop.  If I run my SSIS job on my laptop and update the same tables on my production server, it works fine (no quotation marks).  It is only when the job is run automatically via a scheduled SQL job that this issue occurs.

I would *greatly* appreciate any suggestions anyone might have.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that. The error is shown below. Again, this is because it is trying to put a value like "5" (including the quotation marks) into an integer field.    Error in [Import Open Orders Data]: Data conversion failed while converting column "Column 8" (42) to column "AllocatedQty" (279).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Comment: Perhaps a SQL Server version difference on the laptop, or a configuration file difference?  Does the scheduled job use a config file?  The config could in theory override connection manager properties like the text qualifier.

Comment: What i don't understand yet is why the "5" includes the double quotes if these should be stripped since they are defined as text qualifiers; have you tried a data viewer to see if the quotations are still there just before the insert to the DB?

Comment: Jayvee - I added a dataviewer right before it the final destination and the values do NOT have quotes.  Unfortunately, this is only when the job is run on my laptop, which again, works fine even to the production server.  I am struggling to understand why this only happens on the server's automatic job.

Comment: criticalfix - Good point; I am using a configuration file.  The only attribute I am specifying in the config file is the ConnectionString.  In the past I never had to include the TextQualifier property; it just worked with the quotes by default.  I will experiment with this (by adding it explicitly to the config file) and let you know how I make out.

Comment: Jayvee & criticalfix - In any case, THANK YOU both for your speedy replies!  I appreciate your thoughts & feedback very much.

Comment: criticalfix - Success!  I modified my config file to include the TextQualifier property, removed my derived column "Band-Aid", put that on the server, and the job worked properly.  Great suggestions & THANK YOU very much for helping me!  If you post an actual "answer" below, I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ForEach Loop Container at the package level.  At the task level use a Derived Column transformation.